# Set a c# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have string and I want to vertify if it match this regular expression :

The regex should be 3  Capital letters followed by " - " and Two or more words then ()

Example :

```
BEN - Two Words (m738783)
TST - THREE Words test (a187817)
```

I've tried this regexp

```
Regex userRegex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]3-[A-Za-z]+([A-Za-z0-9])$");
```

But it doesn't work, can someone help ?

I am new with regular expressions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've made the following mistakes:

- Forgot `{}` around `3` (quantifier).
- Forgot about allowing optional space (`\s*`) around the `-`.
- The parentheses were not escaped.
- Forgot to add the `+` quantifier for the character class inside the parentheses.

Here's the regex:

```
@"^[A-Z]{3}\s*-\s*[A-Za-z]+(\s+[A-Za-z]+)+\s+\([A-Za-z0-9]+\)$"
```

Comment: Hello, I use https://regex101.com/ to check your regex but it failed to recognized what's inside the (). It only works when there is only one digit.

Comment: What about 2 or more word?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thanks, I missed this part in the question. Corrected now.

Comment: @aBennouna, I've updated the regex, please try again

Comment: Cheers @AlexShesterov ! it wors ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may try the below regex.

```
@"^[A-Z]{3}\s*-\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)+\s*\([^)]*\)$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yN9hS7/2)